# MySQL create index with LOCK=NONE still locks a table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, rails

I have the following MySQL RoR Migrations:

```
class ReindexRpushNotification < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute("DROP INDEX `index_rpush_notifications_multi` ON rpush_notifications;")
    execute("ALTER TABLE rpush_notifications ADD INDEX index_rpush_notifications_multi (delivered, failed, processing, deliver_after), ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;")
  end

  def down
    execute("DROP INDEX `index_rpush_notifications_multi` ON rpush_notifications;")
    execute("ALTER TABLE rpush_notifications ADD INDEX index_rpush_notifications_multi (delivered, failed), ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;")
  end
end
```

during this migration I'm trying to perform some requests (GET, COUNT, DELETE, UPDATE) but nothing work, all these requests just wait

I found an info about index creation in background here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36064200

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html

but it doesn't work for us

Did anybody try LOCK=NONE?

We use MySQL 5.6.23 on AWS RDS

Answer (score 14):

Looks like I have a clue why it doesn't work

Our table have the following constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT `rpush_notifications_event_id_fk` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `events` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Next, I found here one interesting thing:
https://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlinnodb/entry/online_alter_table_in_mysql

> Online operation (LOCK=NONE) is not allowed in the following cases:
>
> - when adding an AUTO_INCREMENT column,
> - when the table contains FULLTEXT indexes or a hidden FTS_DOC_ID column, or
> - when there are FOREIGN KEY constraints referring to the table, with ON…CASCADE or ON…SET NULL option.

so looks like we have a 3rd case

Comment: Still, shouldn't it throw an error rather than to just proceed while locking production tables and bringing down the wrath of the masses on you?

Comment: Classic MySql silent error. Got bitten by it today. Not happy.

Comment: What about if you use SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; before index creation, and re-enable it afterwards?

Comment: I tested SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 first and it still locked for me unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Consider adding a new index *first*, then `DROP` the old index.  `DROP` should be a lot faster than `ADD`.

Or, if that fails, don't drop the old index.